# Can Gmail display the number of bytes I sent to 'someone@example.com'?

Tags: gmail

I can match all messages that I sent to `someone@example.com` but from what I see it won't display data size.

How do I know the number of bytes that I sent from my Gmail to `someone@example.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you can do from within Gmail. At best, you'll need to work out a way to export all of the messages to another location and use a different tool to sum up their sizes. Even then, that's only going to give you an approximation.